# What effects can directly harm a pilot while they're in a mech?

Tags: lancer-rpg

The IPS-N Blackbeard's SEKHMET NHP explicitly says its control of the mech continues even if the pilot is killed or incapacitated. The HORUS Minotaur's Internal Metafold ability specifies that while within the mech the pilot cannot be harmed in any way.

Why do these effects call out that possibility? Is there a game effect capable of harming pilots while they're mounted, or is it purely a narrative concern?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This same question was asked on [r/LancerRPG](https://www.reddit.com/r/LancerRPG/comments/g4408b/pilot_death_inside_mechs/), with a few results for harming a pilot:

> Yes, they can be. It is somewhat rare, in that only the Pirate template has optional systems that can do it. Additionally the Horus mech Manticore requires pilot death to use the CASTIGATE THE ENEMIES OF THE GODHEAD trait.

The Pirate systems mentioned here are

> #### Coreworm Rockets
>
> System, Limited 1, Full Action
>
> **1d3** miniature drones attach themselves to a character within line of sight and **range 10** and begin drilling into their target’s cockpit. In **1d3+2** rounds, if any coreworms are still attached, they reach the cockpit and savage the pilot, reducing them to **0 HP**. The target knows how many rounds it will take for the drones to bore through, and how many are attached.
>
> The target and allied characters adjacent to them can remove one drone at a time with a successful **Systems** or **Engineering** check as a **quick action**. Additionally, if the target is **Shut Down**, the coreworms are confused and their timer pauses.

<sup>(*Lancer Core Book* pg. 328)</sup>

However, also noted in that Reddit thread are pretty absolute statements that pilots aren’t supposed to die unless they leave their cockpit, and maybe not even then. It’s pretty clear that the coreworms are intended to waste players’ actions, not actually threaten any PC with death.

But of course, in the fiction, pilots are very much supposed to be at risk of death fairly routinely in their dangerous jobs. That could allow the Blackbeard or Minotaur systems to have a little extra value to flesh out a PC’s response to that risk.